# Query sql db and create array

Tags: php, sql, arrays

I am using the below code to  pull all the product codes that have a NULL value on ImageURL row

```
$db = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass);
$stmt = $db->query('SELECT f.ProductCode FROM Flat_table f WHERE f.ImageURL IS NULL');

$noImageProducts = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN, 0);
```

But the $noImageProducts is empty even if i know that i have Products with no url in the ImageURL field.

Comment: Are they null or blank?

Comment: When you say "empty" do you mean an empty array, or is it null, or false? What is it?

Comment: there is also a difference between `null` and `''` (empty string)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is a difference between empty string and NULL.
Try this

```
 SELECT f.ProductCode FROM Flat_table f WHERE f.ImageURL=''
```

if this query returns some value that means ImageURL values are not null.

Comment: $stmt = $db->query('SELECT f.ProductCode FROM Flat_table f WHERE f.ImageURL=""'); has done the thing,  in that case  my fault i forgot to set the default row value as NULL